# How do I convert a set of String Hashes into a number evenly distributed from 1 to 5?

Tags: c#, sorting, hash, load-balancing

I have a set of strings that need to be load-balanced into 1 of 5 positions of a collection containing `List<string>`.

How can I take the string.Hash() and convert that into an Int that is somewhat evenly distributed?

I'm asking so I can figure out a solution for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653609/how-do-i-code-my-asp-net-page-to-parallelize-downloads-across-hostnames) ASP.NET issue.

Comment: If the hash itself is distributed well enough (you'll have to verify this), then `GetHashCode() % 5` should be all you need.

Comment: @John You beat me.  If you post an answer let me know and I'll delete mine.

Comment: @Dave - no problem, I just posted it as a comment because I believe there may be more to the question that I'm missing

Comment: @Dave&John  That's the whole question... dividing by 5 makes sense.  I haven't thought this way about hashes in a long time.  This is what too much CSS design will do to ya..

Comment: @Maker John didn't say to divide by 5, he said to mod by 5.  It's a subtle but important difference.  The modulus operation (the percent sign) in x%y will return the remainder of x divided by y.  The remainder can only be a number between 0 and (y-1).  In your case, taking GetHashCode() % 5, the result must be between 0 and 4, inclusive.  That will split up the values into 5 somewhat even groups.

Comment: @Maker The wiki page for modular arithmetic has more information than you need, but is still interesting: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic

Comment: @Dave - I see, MOD not Divide, thanks for the clarification.  Again too much CSS for my head (and working on a vacation day)

Comment: @Maker I'm enjoying my day off, so I'm glad I could be of assistance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.gethashcode.aspx), the method returns a 32-bit signed integer.  Why not just mod the value by 5?  Assuming that the hashcode is a pseudo-evenly distributed number, the modulus values should also be evenly distributed.